# Iterating through keys in dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, casting

```
nums={'1':'one',
'2':'two',
'3':'three',
'4':'four',
'5':'five'}

nums['6']='six'
for i in range(1,7):
    print(nums[str[i]])
```

Output:

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

I found out alternative ways of doing that when the keys are of int type, but I am still curious as to why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **call** the `str` type:

```
print(nums[str(i)])
```

You were trying to index `str` with `str[i]` (square brackets).